# Como remover dupla barra de rolagem lateral?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

estou com um problema de duplicidade da barra de rolagem lateral na minha página. Utilizei o Framework do Bulma. Alguém sabe como resolver isso? Segue o print do problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
    background-color: #f5f8f9;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

aside {
    background-color: #3a3c40;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px !important;
}

img {
    height: 170px;
}

aside h1 {
    color: #f5a623;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

aside h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

aside .button {
    background-color: #f9a640 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.875em !important;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px 0px rgba(245,166,35, 0.6);
}

aside .redes-sociais {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

aside .redes-sociais li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

aside .redes-sociais li i {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
}

aside .habilidades {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

aside .habilidades h3 {
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

aside .habilidades small {
    color: #8fa4af;
    font-size: 0.750em;
}

aside .habilidades progress {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

aside .habilidades progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: #f1b668 !important;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

article {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

article .content {
    font-size: 0.938em;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 30px;
}

article .content h3 {
    color: #d0021b;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d0021b;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
article .content h3 i {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

article .instituicao h4 {
    font-size: 1.063em;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

article .instituicao h5 {
    font-size: 0.938em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    
}

article .instituicao small {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 0.938em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
<div class="container">
    
  <div class="columns">
  
   <!----Sidebar---->
    <aside class="column is-4">
        
        <img src="#" alt="foto de perfil">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum ipsum</h2>
        <a href="../pm-proj004"/ class="button is-info is-medium">Portfólio</a>
        
        <ul class="redes-sociais">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="habilidades">
            <h3>Conhecimento</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <small>HTML e CSS</small>
                    <progress class="progress is-danger is-small" value="50" max="100">50%</progress>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <small>PHP</small>
                    <progress class="progress is-danger is-small" value="30" max="100">30%</progress>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </aside>
    
    <article class="column is-8">
       <div class="content">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        
        <h3><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>Experiência</h3>
       
       
       <div class="instituicao columns">
            <div class="column is-4">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                <small>Lorem ipsum</small>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>           
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="instituicao columns">
            <div class="column is-4">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                <small>Lorem ipsum</small>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>           
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <h3><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>Formação</h3>
        
        <div class="instituicao columns">
            <div class="column is-4">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                <small>Lorem ipsum</small>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>           
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="instituicao columns">
            <div class="column is-4">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                <small>Lorem ipsum</small>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>          
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </article>
    
  </div>
    
</div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Inclua na pergunta o trecho aonde esses 2 containeres estão, para analisarmos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

com css no elemento que engloba as informações(vc pode descobrí-lo com o inspect do browser):

> overflow-y: hidden

Comment: Entendo, sou novo na comunidade, imaginei que meu comentário fosse pertinente

Comment: `imaginei que meu comentário fosse pertinente` isso mesmo, você pegou o sentido da coisa. como você mesmo disse, é um comentário, então você pode postar como comentário ao invés de resposta, da próxima. E então aguardar mais detalhes ou uma resposta do op para fazer uma resposta decisiva que resolve o problema do op.

Comment: Nem pontos de reputação tenho ainda para comentar, no frigir dos ovos achei assertiva minha resposta, mas aguardemos o parecer de quem perguntou.

Comment: Havia esquecido do mínimo de reputação requerido para comentar, então devo dizer que o erro foi meu desta vez, uma vez que você não tinha alternativa a não ser criar uma resposta, pois não poderia comentar, então me desculpe, rs.

Comment: Deu certo, valeu. :) Eu inclui o overflow-y: hidden no body. Ai a dupla barra desapareceu e ficou só uma.

Comment: mais um up pra vc vai pra 106